# .text update issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Having a bit of an issue in IE (aren't we all).

I've tracked down an problem I'm having to a recursive script that updates a tweets timestamp.

The script works fine, discovering all the date/time stamps to be updated, converts them fine but when it comes to updating the 'time' div it fails. IE doesn't have an issue with `$('#id').text('value')` but I'm obviously doing somehthing wrong. 
Any ideas?

```js
function parseTwitterDate() {
    var timeToAdjust
    $('a[data-scribe="element:full_timestamp"]').each(function() {
        timeToAdjust = $(this).find('time')
        var b = timeToAdjust.attr('datetime').split(/[-t:+]/ig);
        //funky stuff here to generate strTime
        timeToAdjust.text(strTime)
    });
}
```

This works fine in every other browser however in at least IE8 (and 6 but not worried about that) it gets to `timeToAdjust.text(strTime)` and fails.
Note, doesn't have an issue grabbing the 'datetime' attribute `timeToAdjust.attr('datetime')`.

Have tried `.html()` and `$(this).find('time').text(strTime)`

Many thanks for taking a look hopfully someone can point me in the right direction.

Justin

Comment: Which version of jQuery you're using?

Comment: *"...it gets to `timeToAdjust.text(strTime)` and fails..."* Fails *how*? What errors do you see in dev tools?

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski: Why would it matter? All of the calls above were in jQuery 1.0, weren't they?

Comment: `//funky stuff here to generate strTime` we would like to see that, seems interesting.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, jQuery 2.x requires at least IE 9

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because IE8 doesn't support `time` element

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski: And yet I'll bet you money all of those calls still work with it. :-)

Comment: @Spokey: Me too, but the OP says specifically that he/she gets the `datetime` attribute, so...

Comment: @ Justin: Are you doing the html5 dance with IE? E.g., do you have the shim in place that ensures the new element types are recognized by IE?

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski: version 1.11.1 which I believe is the current version. Have tried degrading to 1.9.0/1 which I read were more IE compatible but no luck.

Comment: Not that they are really required, but you should try to put some semi-colons at the end of your lines. When you do not, JavaScript guesses where to put semi-colons, so it is better to be explicit to eliminate the possibility of the interpreter guessing incorrectly, which does happen.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: All IE is saying is "
Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 3
Char: 3215
Code: 0
URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js
"

Comment: @ Justin: Above you told Gregory you were using 1.11.1, not 1.9.0. (Not that it really matters.) About the html5 shim...?

Comment: this won't work in IE8 but will get the datetime, the problem is changing the text! http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/L4ZGv/embedded/result/

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: sorry, didn't see that comment before I posted. You know what, I don't believe I am. I shall drop it in now and see what happens :-D

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: OK, massive DOH! moment - all working as expected. Many thanks for pointing out the obvious :-)

Comment: @Zachary Kniebel: I usually do put semi-colons in - just been faffing a lot :-/

Comment: @Jai: here's the _funky stuff_: [link](http://pastebin.com/bEPWTweR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 and earlier require special steps to ensure that they properly understand that the new HTML5 element types are actually elements. There are tiny scripts out there ([like this one](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/)) which do that work for you.

Without doing that work, lots of aspects of those elements won't work even as just normal elements in IE8 and earlier.

[This JSBin of your code](http://jsbin.com/zuwusabu/2) *(jsFiddle doesn't work with IE8)* fails, but [this one with a shim](http://jsbin.com/zuwusabu/3) works.

Comment: Thanks T.J. I should have seen that - kicking myself just a little ;-)

Comment: @JustinReid: That is a *fascinating* symptom, isn't it? That you can select the element, get an attribute from it, but you can't do an `appendChild` on it. Huh. (I guess IE doesn't know whether those nodes can have children until we tell it...)

Comment: It is a bit weird, at least we know for future and I'll hopefully not make such a rookie mistake again ;-)